# Can airflow load dags file without restart scheduler

Tags: scheduler, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

In my case, i write  a dag file under the dags path. After start the airflow scheduler, it successfully  loads the dag file. However, it fialed to load dag file after changing dag file. Is there any suggestion to loade dag file without restart scheduler?

Comment: Can you clarify on failing to load dag file? The heartbeat should be able to identify the changes and update your dag. If you want to see the update of code in UI, make sure to click refresh as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DAG should be automatically reloaded on the scheduler heartbeat and this will always be done before a DagRun is started.

It can take a while before changes in the DAG are also shown in the web interface, you can manually reload the Dag in the UI by pressing the refresh button in the top right of the Dag view

Comment: Thank you, Brouns!  I have tested some cases, it worked as you just said.